# Which option greeks explain the majority of an option's price move?

Tags: options, option-greeks

I have recently picked up a few derivatives books for leisurely reading and have started to look into the option greeks. There are many e.g. delta, vega, theta, and gamma. There are others which are more obscure (at least to me) e.g. charm and speed.

Is it necessary to know these more obscure/higher order greeks? Or are there just a handful which carry most of the weight when trying to predict where an option price is likely to go? If so what are they?

Cheers -

Comment: Note that greeks don't tell you where an option price is likely to _go_ as they work in both directions (mostly linearly for small movements). They tell you the _sensitivity_ to external inputs.

Comment: Interesting point @D Stanley. However, isn't it true that the greeks give you the sensitivity of an option's value to a given input e.g. the underlying (delta). Hence, if I know where the underlying will go (e.g. +15% within a year), then surely I can figure out a (very) rough idea where the option price will be knowing the delta of that option? Is this then not the same as figuring out where the option price will be?

Comment: Yes if you have a specific position on the underlying price then you can use the sensitivities to calculate the estimated change in option price. But then again, you could also just use a pricing model to price the option with both sets of inputs and compare the results. You don't need the greeks for that.

Comment: @D Stanley. I see what you mean, and it would probably be a lot quicker as well. This also assumes your pricing model is right though no? If the Black Scholes model is shown to be wrong in practice (Vol smile) what do I do?

Comment: Well, sure, but the greeks come from the same model, so if the prices are wrong, then the greeks are wrong, too.

Comment: Also I wouldn't say that B-S is "wrong" per se, only that prices in the real world don't always line up with the assumptions behind it (hence the vol smile)

Comment: yes "wrong" is too strong a word. Presumably practitioners realise this and use other models - surely they wouldn't use Black Scholes?

Comment: Why not? Black-Scholes (to my knowledge) is still the preeminent closed-form option pricing model. Other models like binomial pricing and monte-carlo simulation are much more computationally intensive (and more accurate for American options) and require even more assumptions than B-S.

Comment: Well I mean you wouldn't use pure Black Scholes, presumably you would correct it for its imperfections. If I knew it was imperfect, I would try and correct it somehow - wouldn't you? In which case it would no longer be Black Scholes - it would be some adapted version of it

Comment: In practice, the common way to adapt the model is to use a volatility _surface_ (which usually has a "smile") to determine what the volatility value should be. But the underlying model itself is still B-S - you're just modifying the _inputs_ to make it more accurately match actual prices. It does, however, affect the greeks, since volatility is no longer a constant (it is a _function_ of time to maturity and strike (or underlying, depending on how you look at it).

Comment: @D Stanley, so if I understand you correctly then the BSM is “corrected” via the volatility/sigma parameter, and it is no longer assumed to be a constant? Are there any books/other resources which provide some insight into how this is done, ie how people create a volatility surface and use it with the BSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common  Greeks (delta, gamma, vega, and theta) provide an estimate of  the sensitivity of an option's price to pricing variables  and the associated risk. It's important to note that this is a prediction of option pricing rather than a prediction of what options will make you money.

The importance of the Greeks depends on the level of one's sophistication and the extent of one's option portfolio.  Here's my perspective as applicable to what I do on the retail side:

**Theta** is the rate of change between the option price and time, or time decay. It's important to be aware of it and to understand its non linear behavior but AFAIC, not much more than that.

**Gamma**, a second derivative,  is the rate of change between an option's delta and the underlying asset's price. I have no use for gamma.

**Vega**  represents the the option's sensitivity to volatility and is  useful when trading volatility.  An example would be the large expected expansion in implied volatility going into an  earnings earnings announcement and the large contraction immediately thereafter. It's important for modeling the pricing what ifs of the EA play. Otherwise, day to day, not a significant stat for me.

**Delta**  represents the rate of change between the option's price and a $1 change in the underlying asset's price. This is the most useful Greek for me because when I have a position comprised of 5 to 10 different options, some moving in conjunction with each other and some in opposition,  it's important for me to avoid straying too far from delta neutral. To that end, I sell premium on one side or the other to restore neutral.

The Average Joe who executes simple vanilla strategies like covered calls and cash secured puts with the intention of acquisition or sale at a specific  price doesn't need to know much, if anything,  about the Greeks.  Someone at the other end of the spectrum with a large diversified option portfolio would definitely need the Greeks to manage the risk (the extreme would be an options market maker).

Comment: your answer seems to suggest that the key to understanding option price moves is delta. Have I interpreted your answer incorrectly? What I am trying to understand is - or the purpose of the original question - is why certain option prices move more than others. This may be too broad a question for this forum, but my initial inkling was that the greeks were the answer. Having read a bit further around options it appears implied volatility of the option is extremely important to understand - is this fair?

Comment: The key to understanding option price moves is the  6 option pricing inputs  with volatility and price being the primary movers. Delta is an estimate of how much an option's price will move in reaction to the change in these  variables.  If you want to know why certain option prices move more than others, examine an option pricing formula such as Black Scholes.  If you just want to just observe the magnitude of price change then one by one, vary the values of the inputs one by one and see the effect of changing the value of each each on option price.

Comment: Yes,  implied volatility is extremely important to understand.  It's common to see noob  questions on blogs that ask "Why did the stock move up (down) today  but the value of my  option didn't change?" Hint: It was because of IV.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Baerker I will have a look at modelling the BSM in Excel so I can get a feel for what it is doing.

Comment: Just a bit more on implied volatility: is the holy grail then to find a situation where the underlying is likely to move a lot (based on some analysis) but for whatever reason the market is not anticipating it and so the IVs on the options are very low? I have also read in certain places the IV of an option is used to "correct" for some of the BSM's limitations, is this true? Are there any resources showing how this is done?

Comment: Yes,  you want to find that holy grail.  But tell me, how do you find it and no one else does?  Insider info again (g)?  There are many ways to utilize options.  If your path is directional trading then you must have the ability to find stocks/ETFs that are going to move a reasonable amount in a defined time frame.  When you figure out how to do that consistently, sign me up for your newsletter (g). I can't help you with the belief that IV is used to correct BSM's limitations because I don't concern myself with theory.  I'm just looking to make a buck.

Comment: I knew I should not have said "holy grail" as it doesn't exist in markets. I merely said it to clarify my understanding. However, it is much clearer now why some options will have higher ROIs than others. You make a lot of sense @Bob Baerker - appreciate your help on this once again.

Comment: No worries.  Once you get past that small detail of picking direction or lack thereof in a timely fashion, most of this is just numbers, figuring what strategy will best accomplish your needs and risk tolerance.  There are conservative ways to use options to achieve reasonable goals while limiting risk and there are aggressively ways to abuse.  Without an edge, directional trading is a tough one to succeed at.